# Must provide a file error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, hadoop-yarn

```
PS E:\Block Chain Projects\Ethers-Simple_storage> yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . -o .simplestorage.sol yarn run v1.22.15 warning package.json: No license field $ "E:\Block Chain Projects\Ethers-Simple_storage\node_modules\.bin\solcjs" --bin --abi --include-path no
```

I have attached the screenshot with this...pls check if necessary

```
[SS with error and code && path][1]
```

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible code..

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to post a question in such a way that it is easier for people to reproduce what you did in order to understand the issue. The output you have pasted is inconvenient to grasp without any linefeed. Nor can we see the error in the output. I don't think even the screenshot has been uploaded actually.

Fortunately, I know the context of the question most likely. Try putting it as `. simplestorage.sol` instead of `.simplestorage.sol` (No space after . )

Additionally, I think the --include-path could be problematic.